# Integration of Users from Active Directory into rancher

Tags: active-directory, rancher

Our users are located in Active Directory with an LDAP path something like this:

```
CN=myusername,OU=User,OU=UnitedKingdom,DC=aaa,DC=bbb,DC=ccc
```

Using the `OU=User,OU=UnitedKingdom,DC=aaa,DC=bbb,DC=ccc` as the user search base we can set up the Authentication (https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/admin-settings/authentication/ad/) And I have been able to get things working for UK people only….

However: There are multiple countries in which potential users of the cluster can come from E.G Germany, India etc… We have a lot of users organised in this way and so I wanted to get a  unified view of them in the running rancher UI.

from the docs, User Search Base says

> The Distinguished Name of the node in your directory tree from which
>   to start searching for user objects. All users must be descendants of
>   this base DN. For example: “ou=people,dc=acme,dc=com”.

So I cannot use either multiple search bases (AFAICS)

```
OU=User,OU=UnitedKingdom,DC=aaa,DC=bbb,DC=ccc 

OU=User,OU=Germany,DC=aaa,DC=bbb,DC=ccc”,….
```

or wildcards to specify the users.

```
OU=User,OU=(*),DC=aaa,DC=bbb,DC=ccc
```

Q1) Is there a way to have multiple search bases or use wildcards, or is there a way round this that we can use?

As an alternative

Q2) could use NIS to authenticate. Is there a way to set up NIS as the source of users and groups?

Comment: Can you not just use `DC=aaa,DC=bbb,DC=ccc` as the search base? That will let anyone in your domain authenticate.

Comment: @GabrielLuci I think the way rancher uses the value it expects the users to be directly below the search base - we have the country which then has decendents that are the users. I am not familiar with either rancher or AD but did try that and whilst I currently don't have the error to hand I know it failed in rancher

Comment: The [documentation](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/admin-settings/authentication/ad/) says that "All users must be descendents of this base DN", not "direct descendents". I know how AD works, and you can specify a ["search scope"](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/LDAP%20Search%20Scopes), which is whether to search only one level, or all levels below. But it looks like they don't expose that option to you, so I don't know which they are using. You might have to ask them for support on this.

Comment: @GabrielLuci interesting that gives me a bit of context to look further into this, I do know there is a separate set of options about the user objects - maybe that will contain something - thanks for that pointer

Comment: nope - no way I can see of doing this....

Comment: @GabrielLuci I owe you an apology - you were correct, I made a mistake somehow when trying the higher level search base. Having methodically tried it again I find it does work - if you add an answer I will accept it :) thanks

Comment: No worries, it happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the Search Base to the root of your domain, it should find all users in your domain, rather than only users in one OU:

```
DC=aaa,DC=bbb,DC=ccc
```